# MySql Database connection is not re-establishing in reactive vertx application

Tags: mysql, rx-java2, vert.x

In rxified **vertx** application, a database connection is not re-establishing, if the connection was broken previously (by shutting down mysql service) and it is up again. I have to restart my app to get it work. Below is the stacktrace.

```
ERROR com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.MySQLConnection - Transport failure 
com.github.mauricio.async.db.exceptions.DatabaseException: This channel is not active and can't take messages
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.writeAndHandleError(MySQLConnectionHandler.scala:333)
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.executePreparedStatement(MySQLConnectionHandler.scala:265)
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.codec.MySQLConnectionHandler.sendPreparedStatement(MySQLConnectionHandler.scala:204)
    at com.github.mauricio.async.db.mysql.MySQLConnection.sendPreparedStatement(MySQLConnection.scala:241)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.lambda$queryWithParams$4(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:139)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.beginTransactionIfNeeded(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:305)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.queryWithParams(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:138)
    at io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.queryWithParams(AsyncSQLConnectionImpl.java:46)
    at io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLOperations.querySingleWithParams(SQLOperations.java:94)
    at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.sql.SQLConnection.querySingleWithParams(SQLConnection.java:113)
    at io.vertx.reactivex.ext.sql.SQLConnection.lambda$rxQuerySingleWithParams$2(SQLConnection.java:127)
    at io.vertx.reactivex.impl.AsyncResultMaybe.subscribeActual(AsyncResultMaybe.java:43)
    at io.reactivex.Maybe.subscribe(Maybe.java:4174)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.maybe.MaybeSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(MaybeSubscribeOn.java:54)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note: My JDBC connection creation code is inside **Completable rxStart()** method. But, if I place the code inside **void start()** method, this problem never happens. My app is able to re-connect.

Below is the code snippet inside a vertx verticle.

```
  @Override
  public final Completable rxStart() {      
     return createSQLConnection(config()).ignoreElement();
  }

  private Single<SQLConnection> createSQLConnection(final JsonObject config) {
        return MySQLClient.createShared(vertx,config).rxGetConnection();
  }
```

Part of pom.xml entry

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
     <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
     <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
     <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
     <artifactId>vertx-mysql-postgresql-client</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

It seems Connection status is CLOSED. But why vertx is not recreating connection from pool? I have tried with both vertx **3.7.1** & **3.8** along with rx-java2. This problem is present in both versions.

**Is there a solution for this?**

Note: This is working fine in non rxified vertx app.

Comment: You need to subscribe your createSQLConnection Single. So After ignoreElement() just add subscribe()

Comment: Thanks @Pendula for your reply. But rxStart() returns **io.reactivex.Completable**, if I add subscribe() after ignoreElement(), it will return Disposable object. Moreover, this rxStart() method is called from io.vertx.reactivex.core void start(Future<Void> startFuture) method, where vertx has already supplied the subscribe() method. 
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) {
    **Completable completable = rxStart();**
    if (completable != null) {
      **completable.subscribe(startFuture::complete, startFuture::fail);**
    } else {
      super.start(startFuture);
    }
  }

Comment: I think I have found a solution, I was trying to emit **SQLConnection**. Instead of that, I have emitted **AsyncSQLClient** object. It resolves this issue.